# Final variables as method arguments

Tags: java, final

I was looking at some code from a colleague and saw the following method:

```
public void someMethod(final String str) {
    ...
}
```

which I found odd, as Strings are immutable, anyway. I think it is safe to delete the `final` keyword, there.

I also found the following

```
public void reportProblems(final Collection<IProblem> problems) {
    ...
}
```

There aren't any inner classes around, so.. is there a point in using the `final` keyword there? It looks to me that having the final there is absolutely the same as not having. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The immutability of string is *completely* irrelevant to whether it's declared `final` or not. You could have a final `StringBuilder` parameter, and it would prevent exactly the same thing: reassignment of the variable within the method. You'd still be able to append to the `StringBuilder`. `final` in Java isn't the same as `const` in C++.

Some people like to make everything final when they can - if you know that the value of a variable doesn't change, it can be easier to reason about it. I have a lot of sympathy with that view, and often take the same approach myself - except that I don't actually *force* the issue with the `final` modifier, simply because it adds cruft in the code. If `final` were the default and you had to explicitly use a `mutable` modifier, I suspect that most developers *wouldn't* start making every local variable mutable... they'd just use the default most of the time, as they do now.

So, to come back to the original question: I suspect the developer just wants to be explicit about their style. It's not how I do it, but I can understand the motivation. Another possibility is that at one point there *was* an inner class, but that's gone now and the developer forgot to remove the `final` modifier.

Of course, if your colleague wrote the code, you don't have to guess - just ask!

Comment: As this are such simple methods, I guess the intent was to show to the method's clients that the arguments wouldn't be mutated. But that wouldn't ever happen anyway, right?

Comment: @devoured: The method's clients wouldn't care whether the parameter itself changed value - they wouldn't be able to tell. The final modifier has nothing to do with whether the *object* that the parameter value refers to is mutated or not. You need to keep the two concepts completely separate in your head. It's *possible* that the original coder didn't understand this, of course...

Answer (score 2):

> It looks to me that having the final there is absolutely the same as not having. Am I right?

You are wrong in that it's not *absolutely* the same.

Code like below would compile without *final*...

```
public void someMethod(String str) {
    str = "nonsense"; // will compile fine
}
```

...and won't compile if there's final

```
public void someMethod(final String str) {
    str = "nonsense"; // won't compile
}
```

"What a difference a word makes"

Answer (score 1):

It prevents you from assigning to parameter variable inside the method body. So it does make a difference.